# Basic question on Cosmic Strings

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-string

What is the typical size of [Cosmic String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string) Loops?

If a loop is formed today, what are the restrictions on its size?

I would like to know if there is a distribution of cosmic strings depending on its radius. Is such a distribution valid for loops that may be produced today?